# How to make a sublists for each strings inside a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, sublist

For example, I have this list :

```
word1 =  ['organization', 'community']
```

And I have a function to get a synonyms from the words of the list :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


def getSynonyms(word1):
    synonymList1 = []
    for data1 in word1:
        wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)
        tempList1 = []
        for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
            synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
            for s in synLemmas:
                word = s.replace('_', ' ')
                if word not in tempList1:
                    tempList1.append(word)
        synonymList1.append(tempList1)
    return synonymList1


syn1 = getSynonyms(word1)
print(syn1)
```

and here's the output :

```
[
    ['organization', 'organisation', 'arrangement', 'system', 'administration',
     'governance', 'governing body', 'establishment', 'brass', 'constitution',
     'formation'],
    ['community', 'community of interests', 'residential district',
     'residential area', 'biotic community']
]
```

^ the output above shows that each synsets for both `'organization'` and `'community'` are sublisted inside a list. and then I reduce the level of list :

```
newlist1 = [val for sublist in syn1 for val in sublist]
```

and here's the output :

```
['organization', 'organisation', 'arrangement', 'system', 'administration',
 'governance', 'governing body', 'establishment', 'brass', 'constitution',
 'formation', 'community', 'community of interests', 'residential district',
 'residential area', 'biotic community']
```

^ now all the synsets remain the same strings without sublist. and what I'm trying to do now is to make all the synsets in `newlist1` to be sublisted each other. I expect the output would be like this :

```
[['organization'], ['organisation'], ['arrangement'], ['system'],
 ['administration'], ['governance'], ['governing body'], ['establishment'],
 ['brass'], ['constitution'], ['formation'], ['community'],
 ['community of interests'], ['residential district'], ['residential area'],
 ['biotic community']]
```

I'm trying this code :

```
uplist1 = [[] for x in syn1]
uplist1.extend(syn1)
print(uplist1)
```

but the results is not what I expected:

```
[[], [],
 ['organization', 'organisation', 'arrangement', 'system', 'administration',
  'governance', 'governing body', 'establishment', 'brass', 'constitution',
  'formation'],
 ['community', 'community of interests', 'residential district',
  'residential area', 'biotic community']]
```

It shows two empty lists and two lists of synsets for both `'organization'` and `'community'`

How to make each strings of synsets a sublist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take each element in `syn1` and wrap in `[]` to make it a sublist.

Either with `append`:

```
uplist1 = []
for i in syn1:
    uplist1.append([i])
```

Or with the list comprehension equivalent:

```
uplist1 = [[i] for i in syn1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry sir, not like that. `[[[u'organization', u'organisation', u'arrangement', u'system', u'administration', u'governance', u'governing body', u'establishment', u'brass', u'constitution', u'formation']], [[u'community', u'community of interests', u'residential district', u'residential area', u'biotic community']]]` << it appends a list for synset group but not for each strings

Answer (score 1):

You need to add brackets `[]` to `val` in your list-comprehension to put each `string` in a `list` when creating `newlist1`, for example:

```
newlist1 = [[val] for sublist in syn1 for val in sublist]
```

Comment: @ChristianDean why do that when it can be done when creating `newlist1`?

Comment: Ah, my apologizes. I didn't realize you were also _flattening_ `syn1` and not just iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [`Meow`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6313007)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260103/15497888) who gave me inspiration. I came up with this:

```
upuplist1 = []
for i in newlist1:
    upuplist1.append([i])

print(upuplist1)
```

Here's the output what I expected :

```
[[u'organization'], [u'organisation'], [u'arrangement'], [u'system'], [u'administration'], [u'governance'], [u'governing body'], [u'establishment'], [u'brass'], [u'constitution'], [u'formation'], [u'community'], [u'community of interests'], [u'residential district'], [u'residential area'], [u'biotic community']]
```

Comment: I implement it for list `'newlist1'`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a list comprehension and wrap each item in a list:

```
>>> lst = [[el] for el in newlist1]
[['organization'],
 ['organisation'],
 ['arrangement'],
 ['system'],
 ['administration'],
 ['governance'],
 ['governing body'],
 ['establishment'],
 ['brass'],
 ['constitution'],
 ['formation'],
 ['community'],
 ['community of interests'],
 ['residential district'],
 ['residential area'],
 ['biotic community']]
```